# Integral $\int_{1}^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{t^2 \sqrt{\log{t}}}dt.$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Let $x$ be a real number greater or equal to $3$. I want to compute this integral
$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{t^2 \sqrt{\log{t}}}dt.$$
Any help please?

Comment: why do you not cancel the both $t$?

Comment: $$\int_{1}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{\log t}}\stackrel{t\mapsto e^z}{=}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\log x}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}}=\sqrt{2\log x}.$$

Comment: $u=\ln(t)$ implies $du=\dfrac{1}{t}$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks but I want to consider $t^2 \sqrt{\log{t}}$ in the denominator.

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki: $$\frac{t}{t^2}\,dt = \frac{dt}{t}.$$

Comment: Sorry @JackD'Aurizio I edited the post.

Comment: With the update, such integral is non-elementary, but related to error function evaluated at $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\log x}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio could you clarify what you mean? If I understood you mean that this integral is $=O(\sqrt{1/2 \log{x}})$?

Comment: I mean that the integral is $$ \sqrt{\pi}\,\text{Erf}\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{2}\log x}\right).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $t=e^u$ we have:$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{t^2 \sqrt{\log{t}}}dt=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\log x} {\frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt u}}du$$
and $u=w^2$ gives us:$$I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\log x}} 2e^{-w^2}dw$$
The latter integral has no closed form so we can describe it using error function:
$$I=\sqrt{\pi}erf(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\log x})$$